# Filtering reveresed permutations for a paired list not INTEGERS in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there a means of halting the itertools.perumations cycle at exactly half of the total cycle. 
I Have searched methods of filtering reversed permutations (ABC=CBA OR 123=321)
by comparing the first and last item.

However in my Sourcecode the permutation is on a paired list of points so the comparison is difficult as the points are arbitrary

Comment: Why do you want it to stop half way?  What is your expected input/output.

Comment: Please add your expected input and output. At the moment the question is unclear.

Comment: Well, if you are using a list, then you know the length, and thus, you can calculate how many permuations will be created using math, and simply halt it yourself, no?

Comment: input = paired list = [[A, B], [C, D], [E, F] ......  [X,Y]]    #with N  PAIRS.  The  Permutation XY... EF, CD, AB   and AB,CD,EF ...XY (Reversed) are equivalent in the context of the traveling Salesman problem.

Comment: yes i could manually halt the process!!! Would that be done with a counting variable? So i stop when the count > (n! / 2)